# Get the value of a checkbox field (Boolean field type) from an entity object

Tags: entities

Am trying to get the value of a Boolean field from a node entity, but it returns null whether the field is checked or not checked

```
$field_id = 'field_test_boolean';
/** @var Node $entity */
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->load(220);

dump($entity->get($field_id)->get(0));
```

Not sure what am doing wrong here!!

Comment: `$entity->get($field_id)->get(0)->getValue()['value']` or `$entity->$field_id->value;` You should see a `1` which means it's checked and `0` for unchecked. If you don't, then either the node ID is wrong or your field name is wrong.

Comment: You can also do `$field->get($field_id)->getString()`